# Why does the following Coq code fail to meet Coq's positivity requirement for inductive types?

Tags: coq

I'm currently studying a proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorem written in Coq, by Russell O'Connor. I would like to understand the following section:

> ###### 2.2 Definition of Term
>
> For any given language, a `Term` is either a variable indexed by a natural number
> or a function symbol plus a list of *n* terms where *n* is the arity of the function
> symbol.

I might be confused as a beginner by the use of the term "Term".

I know that in type theory, members of a type are known as "terms".

I also know that in Coq, you can declare new types, which are themselves of type `Type`, like so:

`Language : Type`

I think but am not sure that every term of a type counts as its own type itself. For example, if I declared `English` as a term of type `Language`, I think Coq would immediately assume there is now also a type called `English`. I will check to see if that is true.

I think that the author's definition of a type called `Term`, above, is not related to the other above uses of the word *term*. I think it is rather a synonym for what is also commonly called in logic a "formula". Is that correct, or not?

They define a '*term*' as *either*

- a variable indexed by a natural number, *or*
- a function symbol with a list of terms.

This seems to imply that a 'term' is just a function. I don't understand why they need to define this type (yet).

> My first attempt at writing this in Coq failed.
>
> `Variable L : Language.`

I understand `Variable` to be a keyword of Coq, analogous to keywords like `Parameter`, `Record`, `Definition`, and so on. It seems like they are declaring a variable of type `Language`, to be used in their inductive definition in what follows.

> `Inductive Term0 : Set :=`

I think an inductive type requires that you define a first term and a formula for creating subsequent terms from the first one.

> `| var0 : nat -> Term0`

So if I understand correctly, Term0 is a term of type Set. However, the keyword Inductive means that Term0 is a type, whose terms can be generated from a formula.

The first term of Term0 is called var0. var0 is not of type nat -> Term0. Rather, var0 : nat -> Term0 says that whatever var0 is, it will require a natural number to be instantiated. We have not been given a formula yet for generating var0.

> `| apply0 : forall (f : Functions L) (l : List Term0), (arity L (inr _ f))=(length l) -> Term0.`

I basically don't understand this part at all.

1. Is Functions a keyword that refers to all functions in type L? L is a variable of type Language; Language is a type of type Type. Does this mean that a type always may contains functions in it?
2. What is `inr _ f`?
3. Can someone restate the above line of code in plain English?

> The type (arity L (inr f))=(length l) fails to meet Coq’s positivity requirement for inductive types.

Why is that?

If anyone can answer these questions, it helps me understand the code better.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0505034.pdf

Comment: It might help to read some about first order logic apart from Coq, such as in an undergrad logic textbook. Terminology like “term” is standard in first order logic and in this context they aren’t referring to terms in Coq.  I think a lot of confusion come from the fact that you are looking at a paper which uses Coq as a meta mathematical language to prove facts about first order logic. Enderton is a good undergraduate text book for logic.  So are these course notes: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Teaching/landc_notes.pdf .

Comment: If you tell us what piece of mathematics you are already familiar with, we can suggest some good Coq code to look at that formalizes that piece of mathematics. It is very difficult to learn formalized math by looking at math one is not familiar with. So, for instance, basic number theory, topology, analysis, algebra?